# how to avoid strace in php

Tags: php, stack-trace

I'm having PHP + MySQL code base. If MySQL is stopped and during log-in it fails like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FrameworkException' with message 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)' in /var/www/html/classes/class.connection.php:24 

Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/login.php(15): Connection::getInstance('localhost', 'user', '__password', 'DB') #1 /var/www/html/login.php(73): isDataValid('lakshmipathi.g@...', 'test') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/classes/class.connection.php on line 24
```

How to avoid this stack trace? I want to avoid the username and password displayed like this in case of errors

Comment: catch the exception instead of letting it kill the script?

Comment: you can disable it through error_reporting(0); and or showerrors 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a production server you should hide the error with the [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) directive of your php.ini
The error still be logged but not displayed to the end user.
Turning off the error with [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) is not a good idea if you need to debug

Nevertheless you should handle the exception :

```
try {
//Here the code which can throw an exception
} catch(FrameworkException e) {
 echo 'an exception occured';
}
```

Comment: +1.  In addition to this, you can also take a look at setting your own handler to deal with any uncaught exceptions (i.e. generate a nice error page for the end user, just in case you don't catch everything): http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `@mysql_connect` (or @ + whatever function you call) to suppress any error messages. *And manually spit out some error*. Since you are using some kind of mysterious framework, **you could simply catch the exception**.

But, for live environments, you should disable *any* kind error reporting to the user anyway.

Comment: Hiding a error message with @ is not a good solution. He should handle the error instead. (it's like putting a poster on your wall because there is a hole that you don't want to fix)