# How to prevent password dumping on PDO error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a too many hosts PDO exception in my MySQL database:

```
 exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1129] Host 
'[IP ADDRESS]' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock 
 with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'' in /var/www/libs/Database.php:15
```

I understand this error, but the real problem is in the stack trace which dumps the database name, login and password into the console:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/libs/Database.php(15): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=conf...', 
'[db name]', '[db password]...', Array)
```

As this is an AJAX request, it dumps into the console browser, which is obviously a problem.

How can I avoid this happening? Have I configured PHP incorrectly?

Comment: Is not having the MySQL password in the error logs really important ? If an attacker has access to the logs, he also has access to your `/var/www/libs/Database.php` and can easily get the password if he wanted to... in my opinion I'd say that as long as the logs stay on the server and aren't shared with anyone (via email or other), it's fine.

Comment: Handle errors better. PDO throws instances of `PDOException`, so catch those and handle them gracefully. Any raw error messages shouldn’t be output on a production website anyway, and you should instead use an **error_log** file that isn’t publicly-accessible.

Comment: @André It's an AJAX request, so dumps into the browser console

Comment: Irrelevant. Catch the exception or configure your error reporting settings not to visibly output errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to avoid strace in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262245/how-to-avoid-strace-in-php)

Comment: To summarize: do not try to prevent the dumping on client side. Prevent that the message leaves the server in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As this is an AJAX request, it dumps into the console browser

Of course, PHP (like other server-side languages) is executed in another computer and does not have access to your browser's console. Most likely, neither your PHP nor your JavaScript are designed to handle error conditions gracefully. Some tips:

- Always set `display_errors` to false in your production box. Make sure that error messages are logged instead.
- Tweak your server-side code so it generates valid output even when the DB is down. For instance, if the script is supposed to generate JSON it should send JSON data even on error. To do so:

  - Capture the `PDOException`
  - Log the error details
  - Send JSON data informing that there was an error, e.g.:

    ```
    {"status": "error", "info": "Database is down"}
    ```
- Tweak your client-side code to handle *any* kind of error in the AJAX response, including proper JSON with status=error *and* lack of proper JSON.